# Why can't I send Email on Google app engine?

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, cron

I CAN NOT send email on Google app engine.

The sender_address is the owner of application. I want to use "cron" to send email to someone every day.

Here is my python code:

```
class Send_Email(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.abort(405, headers = [('Allow', 'GET')])
    def get(self):
        if 'X-AppEngine-Cron' not in self.request.headers:
            self.error(403)
        sender_address = "David <z25189347@gmail.com>"
        user_email = "chaowc@mail.ncnu.edu.tw"
        subject = "Work Complete!"
        body = "Picture uploaded!"
        mail.send_mail(sender_address, user_email, subject, body)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'/', MainPage),
                             (r'/sendemail', Send_Email),
                             ], debug=True)
```

Here is my cron.yaml code:

```
cron:
- description: Send Email
  url: /sendemail
  schedule: every day 00:00
  timezone: Asia/Taipei
```

Here is my app.yaml code:

```
handlers:
- url: /sendemail
  script: main.app

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
```

When I run my application at localhost always show:

```
Request to /sendemail succeeded!
```

But when I deploy to  Google app engine , the logs always show wrong messages:

```
 InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender
```

I have no idea where I am doing wrong. Someone help me please! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the sender email address to the list of authorized senders in your Developer console > App Engine > Settings > Application Settings.